# PyORMish losing MySQL connection with Flask

Tags: mysql, orm, flask

I have the following model:

```
class Page(Model):
    _TABLE_NAME = 'page'
    _PRIMARY_FIELD = 'id'
    _SELECT_FIELDS = ('id','title','blurb')
    _COMMIT_FIELDS = ('title','blurb')
```

And in Flask, I have:

```
@app.before_request
def setUp():
    global page
    Model.db_config(databaseConfigDict)
    page = Page(1)
```

I'm using Flask 0.9 and PyORMish 0.8.

One in a few hundred requests I see "MySQL Server Has Gone Away" in the Apache error.log. This doesn't happen when I use the SQLite Model, only with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *was* a [known issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/2) with MySQLdb's default configuration.

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/webgovernor/pyormish/commit/b3cbe26207cad7423632de253fcf112930220ad3) since [Pyormish 0.9.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyormish), I recommend upgrading. Since 0.8, most everything is backwards compatible, but `get_by_field()` has been renamed to `get_by_fields()`, so you'll want to check for those cases in your code.

The short answer is:

```
sudo pip install pyormish --upgrade
```

And BTW, thanks for using PyORMish!